# How to get server changed data with out ajax call

Tags: jquery, ajax, node.js, websocket

Hi i have a scenario  where i will be hitting url with ajax call in order to get data from server. AJAX request will be send with additional headers like token which i will obtain after successful login but my case is i need to get data only when there is any change in server side i dnt want to make a ajax call with setTimeout or setInterval. For that i came across following scenario's:

> 1) Making call with websockets [issue: Not able to add additional
>   headers].
>
> 2) Server side events [issue: No support for ie versions].
>
> 3) Socket io [This way it is possible but if no other options are
>   there then i will go with this, because for now i am new to node
>   development and i dnt want to host my file in server at current time].

So if there is any other possible way please let me know it will be very helpful.

Any where content i mentioned wrong please correct me.

Thanks.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[Socket.io](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Socket.IO) is just a library that uses WebSockets or AJAX internally.

You can use WebSocket and send the token as a message. Or, set a cookie during the login process and reconnect the WebSocket since the WebSocket connection will carry the cookie when reconnecting

Take a look to this article: https://devcenter.heroku.com/articles/websocket-security#authentication-authorization

Comment: Direct in the way u said but am not able to connect. Can you please go through my fiddle link and correct me if am doing wrong.                   http://jsfiddle.net/7kb9gh24/

Comment: Check http://jsfiddle.net/jq50s60u/1/ . You cannot set cookies in a different domain. So if the web page is in a different domain than the websocket server, the cookie won't be sent. If the server that logs you in return a cookie, and the websocket server is in the same domain that the login server, it will be sent. In this example, you cannot set a cookie in jsfiddle.net and then expect it to be sent to echo.websocket.org

Comment: Understood but my actual scenario is i am trying to develop a browser extension where i will be showing notifications. I tried sending token in message but am not able to connect.                     Initiation of websocket it self am getting "HTTP Authentication failed" then how it will go to onopen in order to take token.

Comment: Is there any other way to achieve this case??

Comment: The server has to support websockets. Websockets are not something that you use to connect to an AJAX service and stay connected, it is a totally different thing. If the server supports websockets, it has to provide a way of authenticaion under the websocket protocol limitations. If you are developing also the server,  you can add that functionality, otherwise you will have to add the owners to implement it.